# How to use Action cable in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, actioncable

I'm using Activeadmin to make a dashboard page and Devise for User authorize. I have 2 model are Member (regular user) and User(admin user). When I use the Action cable feature to show the user appearance or not then just only Member user received these broadcast. The problem is how the User model can receive these broadcast too ?

Thank you for your time and sorry for my clumsy English

My connection

module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_member

```
def connect
  self.current_member = find_verified_member
  # self.current_user = find_verified_member
  logger.add_tags 'AcctionCable', current_member.email
end

protected
  def find_verified_member

    # if current_member = Member.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:member_id])
    if verified_member = env['warden'].user
      verified_member
    else
      reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
  end
```

end
end

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to broadcast to a channel for users whenever a member establishes connection with ActionCable. If so, in the `def subscribed` method for whatever channel member is subscribing to that you wish for the admin users to be notified of, run a broadcast job to a channel accessible to all admin users. Admin members can establish a client to subscribe to this channel in order to receive these broadcasts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a chat with actioncable and activeadmin here is an example of a gem that does that. [active_admin_chat](https://github.com/rootstrap/active_admin_chat)

Or maybe you can try the piece of code below.

```
def connect
  self.current_member = find_verified_member
end

protected

def find_verified_member
  cookies_signed = cookies.signed
  admin_user_id = cookies_signed['admin_user.id']
  if admin_user_id
    AdminUser.find(admin_user_id)
  else
    User.find(cookies_signed['user.id'])
  end
end
```